# How to convert unit values in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv table which look like below. I want to convert all the values from column[1] onwards, from current values of knots to m/s using formula: value/0.514444. I then want to save the file as a new csv file. I tried to list the for loop as below but i'm getting errors. I am new to python, unsure of what I am doing wrong. Is there a way to change the values like written in my draft, without reading the csv as an array? Any comments would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

The table looks like this:

```
number,  column1,   column2                                                 
1,       33.1730,   30.7346                                               
2,       33.1730,   30.5905                                                
3,       32.8460,   30.5905
```

My script which is giving error:

```
import pandas as pd


eventtable = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Temp\test\test_combined.csv')

for col in range(1,len(eventtable.columns)):
    for row in range(1,len(eventtable)):
        eventtable[row,col]/0.514444

eventtable.to_csv(r'C:\Temp\test\test_combined_convert.csv')
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text. Post text.

Comment: Also, copy the contents of the CSV file from a text editor. Don't copy what Excel shows, that's useless.

Comment: Also, make an honest attempt. Asking us to do all the work for you is a no-no on StackOverflow. If you don't know how to use a loop, there are tutorials. If you do not know what libraries to use, you should do some research (asking for libs is also a no-no)

Comment: Sorry Mike, Tomalak, I have edited the question to be more specific and with clearer details. I tried to script the for loop but I am missing something which I am unsure of. I thnk I am missing something in         eventtable[row,col]/0.514444....but I am not sure what should be added. Please, appreciate if you can help me with some pointers. Thanks.

Comment: What is the error? Post a full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `applymap` to apply a function to an entire dataframe. Do set `number` as index column when reading the csv to avoid the function being applied to that column as well:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''number,  column1,   column2                                                 
1,       33.1730,   30.7346                                               
2,       33.1730,   30.5905                                                
3,       32.8460,   30.5905'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=',\s+', index_col='number', engine='python')
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x/0.514444)
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Result:

| number | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 64.4832 | 59.7433 |
| 2 | 64.4832 | 59.4632 |
| 3 | 63.8476 | 59.4632 |

Comment: Thank you RJ Adriaansen! I will try out the method.

Comment: RJ's method works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it solved your issue.